# What is my rosjava setup missing?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working through the Pharos Lab's rosjava tutorial, which is located [here](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_ROSJava_to_Program_the_iRobot_Create_to_Move#Create_the_Program)

Here is my build.gradle file contents:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'edu.ycp.RobotMover'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
version = '0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'ros.my_stack'
```

When I run gradle installApp, I don't get any errors. However, if I try to run my application from the command line with:

```
./build/install/robot_mover_java/bin/robot_mover_java edu.ycp.RobotMover
```

I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Did I forget a step in the process? Does the build.gradle file need something else? I am calling robot_mover_java from within the ROS package that I created.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41515/what-is-my-rosjava-setup-missing?/) by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial appears to be rather out of date. I suggest you start with the tutorials in the [rosjava documentation](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0